# Count of values, for each group, less than a quantile of the whole column performed on each column

Tags: r, quantile, binning

I have a data.frame with two groups and two variables (other than the group variable), for example:

```
set.seed(1729)
temp <- data.frame(group=c(1,2),value1=rnorm(12),value2=rnorm(12))
temp = temp[order(temp$group),]
# group      value1      value2
#     1  0.21531616  0.08679615
#     1  1.08604925  0.36344973
#     1  1.04225410  0.53281840
#     1 -1.40843189  0.52096971
#     1 -0.07130541 -0.47550518
#     1  0.18839979  1.96241245
#     2  0.18374784 -0.64102941
#     2  0.02871298 -0.67746579
#     2  0.08826553 -0.32679060
#     2  0.05522136 -0.31371224
#     2  0.36086719 -0.10004339
#     2 -0.55618926  1.22760816
```

I calculate the quantiles of temp$value1 & temp$value2

```
qt1 = quantile(temp$value1,probs = c(0.25,0.5,0.75))
qt2 = quantile(temp$value2,probs = c(0.25,0.5,0.75))
```

For each group, I need
(1) the count of number of values of temp$value1 < qt1[1] (2) the count of number of values of temp$value1 < qt[2] (3) the count of number of values of temp$value1 < qt1[3]. Similarly, six values (two groups & three quantiles) of counts for temp$value2.

As a code, it is (I manually copied each group+variable into a vector to illustrate what I want)

```
g1v1=c(0.21531616,1.08604925,1.04225410,-1.40843189,-0.07130541,0.18839979)
length(g1v1[g1v1<qt1[1]])
length(g1v1[g1v1<qt1[2]])
length(g1v1[g1v1<qt1[3]])

g2v1=c(0.18374784,0.02871298,0.08826553,0.05522136,0.36086719,-0.55618926)
length(g1v2[g1v2<qt1[1]])
length(g1v2[g1v2<qt1[2]])
length(g1v2[g1v2<qt1[3]])

g1v2=c(0.08679615,0.36344973,0.53281840,0.52096971,-0.47550518,1.96241245)
length(g2v1[g2v1<qt2[1]])
length(g2v1[g2v1<qt2[2]])
length(g2v1[g2v1<qt2[3]])
#similarly for g2v2
```

The output has to be a data.frame like:

```
# group value1.25.ct value1.50.ct value1.75.ct value2.25.ct value2.50.ct value2.75.ct
#     1            2           2           4             1            1        4
#     2            1           4           5             2            5        5
```

Please recommend an efficient approach. Thank you.

Comment: A combination of `table` and `cut` should help.

Comment: Than you @TheComeOnMan. Any good example that you can refer me to?

Comment: The examples in R should be easy enough to follow.